# Owl-carousel картинки вместо dots

Tags: html, jquery, owl-carousel

Как сделать что бы вместо dots в owl карусели были изображения?

JS:

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  items: 1,
  nav: false,
  dots: true,
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="owl-carousel container owl-theme">
  <div class="item">
    <h4><img src="img/13.jpg" alt=""></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4><img src="img/13.jpg" alt=""></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4><img src="img/13.jpg" alt=""></h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://github.com/gijsroge/OwlCarousel2-Thumbs

Comment: https://codepen.io/sirnightowl/pen/JoJwrE - вариант без дополнительного плагина

Comment: @YozhEzhi  Спасибо))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

codepen.io/sirnightowl/pen/JoJwrE - вариант без дополнительного плагина – YozhEzhi 1 мар в 9:11

Answer (score 0):

Еще один вариант, тоже без плагинов. Работает даже когда каруселей больше одной.

JS, jQuery:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        let outs = document.querySelectorAll('.owl-out');

        for (let out of outs) {

            let owl = out.querySelector('.owl-carousel');
            let btns = out.querySelectorAll(':scope .thumb');

            let owlJq = $(owl);
            owlJq.owlCarousel({
                items: 1,
                loop: false,
                margin: 10,
                nav:true,
                dots: false,
            });

            for (let btn of btns) {
                btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
                    owlJq.trigger('to.owl.carousel', [$(this).index()]);
                })
            }
        };

    });

</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="owl-out">
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <div class="item" style="width:250px; height: 200px; background-color: gray; font-size: 25px; color: white;">1</div>
        <div class="item" style="width:250px; height: 200px; background-color: gray; font-size: 25px; color: white;">2</div>
        <div class="item" style="width:250px; height: 200px; background-color: gray; font-size: 25px; color: white;">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbs">
        <button class="thumb" role="button">btn 1</button>
        <button class="thumb" role="button">btn 2</button>
        <button class="thumb" role="button">btn 3</button>
    </div>
</div>
```